# NGINX responds to pings, rejects requests, times out on DNS - potential hairpining

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, port-forwarding, nginx

Running Ubuntu Server v23 with NGINX and a "static" IP address (via noip).
From my Server I ping the public IP and see this:

Via Web Server: IP `192.168.1.43`

```
root@websrv:/etc/nginx/conf.d# ping TheSite.com
PING TheSite.com (50.47.211.xxx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 50-47-211-xxx.evrt.wa.ptr.ziplyfiber.com (50.47.211.xxx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms
```

I ping the same IP from a LAN windows machine:

```
Pinging 50.47.211.xxx with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 50.47.211.xxx: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63
```

Then I try to resolve DNS:

```
C:\Users\shawn>curl TheSite.com --verbose
*   Trying 50.47.211.xxx:80...
* connect to 50.47.211.xxx port 80 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to TheSite.com port 80 after 21052 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Trying to curl the IP gives the same result. However, if I curl the LAN IP of the Server, it works:

```
root@websrv:/home/shawn# curl 192.168.1.43 --verbose
*   Trying 192.168.1.43:80...
* Connected to 192.168.1.43 (192.168.1.43) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.43
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 09 Oct 2023 07:09:01 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 615
< Last-Modified: Mon, 23 May 2022 23:59:19 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "628c1fd7-267"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.43 left intact
root@websrv:/home/shawn#
```

and same thing from the windows box on LAN:

```
C:\Users\shawn>curl 192.168.1.43 --verbose
*   Trying 192.168.1.43:80...
* Connected to 192.168.1.43 (192.168.1.43) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.43
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
```

This is my NGINX config:

```
worker_processes  2;
user            www-data;


events {
        use             epoll;
        worker_connections  128;
}

error_log         /var/log/error.log; #info;


http {
    server_tokens off;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    charset             utf-8;

    index      index.html


   access_log   /var/log/access.log     combined;

    sendfile        on;

    server {
        server_name  TheSite.com;
        listen       80;
#        server_name  TheSite.com;

        location        /{

#       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#       proxy_pass http://localhost:80/;
#       auth_basic           "closed site";
#       auth_basic_user_file htpasswd;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

I Have disabled ALL the fire wall (`uwf disable`) and in my router (orbi pro) Set a DMZ to the server LAN IP, port forward 80, and Disable Port Scan and DoS Protection:

[image]

I have been banging my head on this for days, and this is my first time setting up an ubuntu web server.. I am offically stuck at this point... I am at a total loss, I throw myself at your mercy and humbly beg for your help super user community.

Comment: accessing the DMZ from within the LAN is not always possible (dependant on the router) - you're more likely to get results using port forwarding as long as the router supports "hairpinning" - by the way, if you test from outside your LAN, you're likely to see it's working

Comment: This looks like a case of [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback)  . Support must be available on the home NAT/router or else workarounds devised.

Comment: oh ok - so that must be why I see so many people testing this on their phones…